# Text Evaluation program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am in a rut.
I am trying to write a program where a paragraph of text is checked for a word inserted by the user. The program should state which line the word is at and how many times it is present in that line.
Here is my code so far:

```
def linecount(t, w):

    f=0
    s=[]
    c=0
    for x in t:
        if not(x == '\n'):
            s=list(s)+list(x)

        c=c+1
        #where this checks if x is a return or not(thus limiting to each line)
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: #Nice how people can vote down and view the question but can't offer any pointers on how to proceed, especially considering that not everyone was born a programmer...

Comment: For sub-string check use the `in` operator : `'x' in 'fox'`. For count, use `str.count`: `'foo foo foo'.count('oo')`.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Also see `t.find(w)`.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I think you can just use the `find` method of strings:

```
def findCount(line, word):
    count = 0
    idx = line.find(word)
    while idx >= 0: # word has been found at least once
        count += 1
        # Searching the next occurence
        idx = line.find(word, idx + len(word))
    return count
```

Then, you can just iterate over the lines as you did:

```
def findCounts(lines, word):
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        print "Lines %s: found %s times word %s..." % (i, findCount(line, word), word)
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> text = '''lapin souris lapin lapin\nlapin lapin\n\n\nchat chien\n lapin chat chien'''.split('\n')
>>> print text
['lapin souris lapin lapin', 'lapin lapin', '', '', 'chat chien', ' lapin chat chien']
>>> findCounts(text, 'lapin')
Lines 0: found 3 times word lapin...
Lines 1: found 2 times word lapin...
Lines 2: found 0 times word lapin...
Lines 3: found 0 times word lapin...
Lines 4: found 0 times word lapin...
Lines 5: found 1 times word lapin...
```

**--EDIT--**

Or, as hcwhsa pointed out, you can replace my needlessely complex `findCount` by `line.count(word)`...

Comment: I have attempted line.count in the past but I can't seem to get it to return the exact word...it returns all words that have the given word.

EX: findcount('Their cat is on the table', 'the') returns 2 and not 1...

But thanks to all, it is much clearer now

Comment: Yes, it only counts _substrings_, not _words_. To do that, you can either modify the `findCount` such that after a successful find, it looks ahead one character to make sure it is a 'word' (i.e. followed by space, comma, period...) or look at *Regular Expressions* (regexp module here: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) which basically provide a nicer framework for doing the same thing.